# Add row to gridview in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview on my ASP website that needs to process each row and, based on a condition, either keep the row or remove it and add it to another gridview. I've figured out how to remove the row by simply using one of the built-in methods. Everything I find online is telling me to use the "gridview.Rows.Add(row)" property, however it creates the following error in Visual Studio:

"'Add' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'."

- grdTraining is the "master" gridview containing the results to be examined.
- grdExpTraining is the "secondary" gridview that takes the rows pulled from the "master."
- grdTraining_RowDataBound is a method that gets called everytime the website finds records to place into grdTraining.

  ```
  Protected Sub grdTraining_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdTraining.RowDataBound

     ' Grey out expired training courses
     Dim row As GridViewRow
     row = e.Row
     Dim incomingDate As String
     incomingDate = row.Cells(4).Text.ToString()

     If (e.Row.RowType <> DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
         Exit Sub
     End If

     Try
         Dim expDate As Date = incomingDate
         If (expDate < DateTime.Today) Then
             grdExpTraining.Rows.Add(row)    'The line that is causing the error
             grdTraining.DeleteRow(trnIndex)
         End If
     Catch ex As Exception
     End Try

     trnIndex += 1
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Sorry about that. Added it to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add a row to my grid view using the following code. I basically had to re-do the entire process again, treating the nested gridview like a completely new gridview. This also only works if you plan on placing one row in the nested gridview. You can play with the scope of the DataTable and DataRow declarations to do otherwise.

```
            'Create datatable and columns
            Dim dtable As New DataTable
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("StateCode"))
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CourseDesc"))
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Hours"))
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("EffectiveDate"))
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ExpirationDate"))
            dtable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LastChange"))

            'Create counter to prevent out of bounds exception
            Dim i As Integer = row.Cells.Count

            'Create object for RowValues
            Dim RowValues As Object() = {"", "", "", "", "", ""}

            'Fill row values appropriately
            For index As Integer = 0 To i - 1
                RowValues(index) = row.Cells(index).Text
            Next

            'create new data row
            Dim dRow As DataRow
            dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
            dtable.AcceptChanges()

            'now bind datatable to gridview... 
            grdExpTraining.DataSource = dtable
            grdExpTraining.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use CopyTo on the grdExpTraining, add the row to the ArrayList, and then initialize the GridViewRowCollection again.

Answer (score 0):

if u like to auto rows on gridview like get some students info from db record count is n, then this might be help.

HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="1" DataKeyNames="Roll_No,ID_Number,Marks,Remarks" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll No">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="txtRoll_No" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="txtID_Number" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarks" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="text" 
            Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" CssClass="text" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
      </asp:GridView>
```

VB.NET CODE

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim i As Integer
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Roll_No"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID_Number"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Marks"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Remarks"))
For i = 1 To 10
  Dim dRow As DataRow      
  dRow = dt.NewRow
  dt.Rows.Add(dRow)    
  dt.AcceptChanges()      
Next i
'now bind datatable to gridview... 
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()

With GridView1
  For i = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Roll_No As Label = DirectCast(.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("txtRoll_No"), Label)
    Dim ID_Number As Label = DirectCast(.Rows(i).Cells(2).FindControl("txtID_Number"), Label)        
    Roll_No.Text = i + 1
    ID_Number.Text = "2014-01-" & i + 1
  Next
End With
```

Where you can edit the marks and remarks and INSERT INTO DB if you want to insert single row one after another then just remove the loops.